# jQuery::Ajax success never occurs

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have an ajax call in the head section of my index.html

```
$(function() {
  alert("Hello, World!");
  $.ajax({
    method: 'get',
    url : 'php/getRecord.php?color=red',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) { 
        alert(data); 
    }  
  });
});
```

For some reason, that alert(data) never gets called but the "Hello, World!" gets called. Am I doing something wrong? The PHP file does give me data when testing it directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably getting an error somewhere.

Check the HTTP request in Firebug or Fiddler and make sure that it's doing what you expect.

Add an `error:` handler and see whether it gets fired.

Comment: @SLaks: Added that as , `error: function(e) { alert(e); }` and it shows [object XMLHttpRequest] :|

Comment: @Legend - Instead of `alert(e)`, do a `console.log(e)` and inspect the error object in the console. Or step through code with a debugger.

Comment: @Anurag: Doing that now... :) Shows parsererror and undefined. Precisely:  XMLHttpRequest { readyState=4,  more...} parsererror undefined

Comment: +1 to using a http sniffer like Fiddler to see what's actually being returned from the server.

Comment: There was a comma missing from my JSON return data :) Thanks a lot for the help...

Comment: **You should use a PHP JSON library**.  Don't concatenate it yourself.

Comment: @SLaks: Point taken. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Pick whatever function will do the job.  (I don't know PHP)

Comment: @SLaks: Sure. Using something that came up in Google :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried defining an error callback to see if there's a problem?

```
,error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(textStatus);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so it throws a parser error. I just moved the function from inside a plugin to directly inside index.html and it throws this error. Guess something went wrong somewhere.